# Call a function outside of a dynamic jquery slider

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am dynamically creating my sliders and in the "Slide" event and "Stop" event I would like to call a function that is defined in the non dynamic content. I can get the functions to work if I create them each time with the slider, but that seems like a lot of redundant code?

Non Dynamic function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var converSecondsToMinutes;

convertSecondsToMinutes = function(secondsEntered){
    var secondsEntered = secondsEntered;

    var time = parseInt(secondsEntered,10);
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time;

    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = time % 60;

    minutes = minutes < 9 ? "0"+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 9 ? "0"+seconds : seconds;
    var newTime = minutes+":"+seconds
    console.log(newTime);
    return newTime
}
});
```

Dynamic jQuery slider

```
    <?php
query...
result...
for(...){
?>
<Script>
$( "#slider"+<?php echo $id; ?> ).slider({ 
            animate: true ,
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            //dynamic grab this
            max: <?php echo $playtime_seconds; ?>,
            step: 0.01,
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                ....
            },
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                audio = ....
                audio.currentTime = ui.value;
                progress_seconds = parseFloat(audio.currentTime.toFixed(2));
                progress_seconds = $(function(){convertSecondsToMinutes(progress_seconds);});

                $('#progress_seconds'+<?php echo $id; ?>).html(progress_seconds);

            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                ....
                }
            }

        });


    });

}
```

I cut and paste the parts of the code that were important to the question.

This is the line that is not working: $('#progress_seconds'+).html(progress_seconds);

Answer (score 1):

You edited just after I commented, so my comment no longer made sense, the $(function(){ part of your code is not necessary, try just using:

```
progress_seconds = converSecondsToMinutes(progress_seconds);
```

And spelling errors in code are a real issue with me, conver has a t at the end.

There is also no need to wrap your function in $(document).ready(), declare it like this:

```
function convertSecondsToMinutes(secondsEntered)
{
    var time = ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, still get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: convertSecondsToMinutes is not defined

Comment: Have you changed it to convert both in the snippet I posted and the function declaration?